# Start interval when the next minute starts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, setinterval

In an agenda/calendar app I'm working on, I display a line to indicate the current time. I want to update the position of this line every minute.

If I start a setInterval function when the calendar component did mount or will mount, there is a change that it starts at the 59th second (or just not the 1st second) and the time will always be different from the time that the device is showing (computer, smartphone, ...).

But I would like that both times are matching. So I was wondering if it is possible to start the interval when a new minute starts of if there is another way to get a time update.

EDIT: Current code

```
componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({ currentTime: new Date() })
    }, 60 * 1000);
}
```

Comment: Just use new Date in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get fairly close, by calculating the number of seconds until the next minute, and performing a timeout on the difference.

```js
(function showTime(){
  console.log('update time');
  var time = document.getElementById('time');
  var now = new Date();
  
  time.innerHTML = `${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}`;
  setTimeout(showTime, (60 - now.getSeconds()) * 1000);
})();
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SetTimeout to call a function that repairs any deviation for each iteration and relaunches with a new call to setTimout.

```
function repairAndRelaunch (cnt) {
    // capture current secs
    var secs = (new Date()).getSeconds();
    // relaunch with corrected seconds - limit iterations for testing
    if (5 > cnt++) setTimeout('repairAndRelaunch(' + cnt + ')', (60-secs)*1000); 
    // log to observe discrepencies
    console.log('for cnt = ' + cnt + ', secs = ' + secs);
};

// test control flow
window.onload = function() {repairAndRelaunch(0);};
```